# Git revert fails to recover removed file

Tags: git, github

I have a series of commits

```
A --> B --> A'
```

The changes in commit `B` were to execute `git rm myfile` and add `myfile` to `.gitignore`. I then pushed commit `B` to remote. But I realized I forgot to add the `--cached` option to `git rm`, so `myfile` was actually deleted from my local repository, whereas I just wanted to stop tracking it and delete it from remote.

In order to fix this, I made commit `A'`, which was nothing but a `git revert HEAD~`, reverting back to `A`. It successfully reverted back to `A`. But `myfile` did not reappear.

If I do `git ls-tree A` then `myfile` is there, but if I do `git ls-tree A'` then `myfile` is not there. What is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you wanted to run `git revert HEAD` to get back the file.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to get file `myfile` from commit `A` to your disk :

```
git show A:myfile > myfile

# or :
git restore --worktree -s A -- myfile
```